# windows 10 updates - install on shutdown instead of immediately

Tags: windows-10, updates, auto-updates

Windows 10 Pro installs updates whenever the system feels like it. Sometimes this is extremely inconvenient, like installing updates while on a presentation or working on some important files.
On previous versions of windows I switched to "download updates but install manually", usually installing the updates on shutdown.

How can I set this behaviour on windows 10 Pro? (if this can only be done on Windows 10 Enterprise I have access to that, too)

Update: My main question is: how do I disable automatic update installation. Usually update installations hit me during some important work. It may even trigger an automatic reboot (using a popup right in the middle of me typing something, so my typing will count as popup answer). 
At minimum it will slowdown my PC during some activity where I don't want slowdown. 
For my tablet (Surface Pro 3) once it even installed the updates after I closed the keyboard and put the device away in a bag. Lucky me I noticed the ventilation working hard (and useless, in a bag), otherwise it probably would have fried my surface pro 3.

Really, fully automatic updates suck. How do I get rid of them. Installing on shutdown would be nice, but any other solution is better than automatic installation.

Comment: Windows 10 no longer offers that, welcome to a Windows brave new world.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Install Windows 10 updates on shutdown](http://superuser.com/questions/956178/install-windows-10-updates-on-shutdown)

Comment: My main point is disabling automatic installation because it usually hits me in the middle of some important work.

Comment: As above, this is by design in W10 with their SaaS and user is an idiot model. Return to 7 if you'd like update control.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this tool can help (I got no idea if it is valid and virus free, though):
http://www.wilderssecurity.com/threads/windows-update-minitool.380535/

Answer (score 0):

You can always turn off automatic updates and install them manually. There's open source simple solution how to do this.
[Sources at Github](https://github.com/slavanap/Windows10ManualUpdate)

[Direct link to binary](https://github.com/slavanap/Windows10ManualUpdate/releases/download/1.0/w10mu.exe) (github release section)