# Can Windows 10 do an Update and Shutdown?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

After my Windows 10 system gets an update I can clearly see the 'Update and Restart' option, but what happened to 'Update and Shutdown'?

Comment: This was added back in as of Windows 10 version 1511. Which is a free upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The <strike>feature</strike> button is **removed from Windows 10**.

Per this [source](https://superuser.com/a/959019/498587), this seems like the best alternative:

> If you hold shift while clicking the "Shut Down" button, it will install the updates on your *next boot*.

However honestly I don't even think you need to do that. Whenever I've had updates pending (like last night) and I simply clicked "shut down" my PC ***always*** installed them ***before*** shutting down.

Comment: This doesn't work on Windows 10 version 1709. After shutting down in this way and then booting, the update is still pending a restart.